# Unmarshal on reflected value

Tags: json, reflection, go, unmarshalling

[Here is the code](http://play.golang.org/p/n0HwJld7It)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "encoding/json"
    "reflect"
)

var (
    datajson []byte
    //ref mapp
)

type mapp map[string]reflect.Type

type User struct {
    Name string
    //Type map[string]reflect.Type
}

func MustJSONEncode(i interface{}) []byte {
    result, err := json.Marshal(i)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return result
}
func MustJSONDecode(b []byte, i interface{}) {
    err := json.Unmarshal(b, i)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

}
func Store(a interface{}) {
    datajson = MustJSONEncode(a)
    //fmt.Println(datajson)
}

func Get(a []byte, b interface{}) {
    objType := reflect.TypeOf(b).Elem()
obj := reflect.New(objType)
//fmt.Println(obj)
MustJSONDecode(a, &obj)
fmt.Printf("%s", obj)
    }

func main() {

    dummy := &User{}
    david := User{Name: "DavidMahon"}

    Store(david)
    Get(datajson, dummy)

}
```

In the Get function

```
func Get(a []byte, b interface{}) {
    objType := reflect.TypeOf(b).Elem()
obj := reflect.New(objType)
//fmt.Println(obj)
MustJSONDecode(a, &obj)
fmt.Printf("%s", obj)
    }
```

I am unable to unmarshal the json into the underlying object type.

Whats wrong here? I am so stuck here. Something very simple yet so difficult to figure out.

Thanks

**UPDATE**::Goal of this problem is to retreive a fully formed object of type passed in Get function.

The approach mentioned by Nick on the comment below doesnot get me the actual object which I already tried before. I can anyways retrieve the data (even when the object has recursive objects underneath) in a map like this

```
func Get(a []byte) {
    var f interface{}

    //buf := bytes.NewBuffer(a)
    //v := buf.String()
    //usr := &User{}

    MustJSONDecode(a, &f)
    fmt.Printf("\n %v \n", f)
}
```

However I need the actual object back not just the data. Something like `user := &User{"SomeName"}` where I need `user` object back from Unmarshall. The trick is somewhere in reflection but dont know how.

Comment: Reflect won't do what you seem to think it will. You can't construct an arbitrary object using it. You could probably cobble something together using reflect and unsafe but really you should rethink what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks I am closing this thread. Thanks for taking time. +1'd your answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm confused as to why you want to do this, but here is how to fix it

```
func Get(a []byte, b interface{}) {
    objType := reflect.TypeOf(b).Elem()
    obj := reflect.New(objType).Interface()
    //fmt.Println(obj)
    MustJSONDecode(a, &obj)
    fmt.Printf("obj = %#v\n", obj)
}
```

Note the call to [Interface()](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Interface).

[Playground link](http://play.golang.org/p/cp6RCEMFEJ)

It seems to me that you are going to a lot of trouble to make an empty `&User` when you already have one in `b`, eg

```
func Get(a []byte, b interface{}) {
    MustJSONDecode(a, &b)
    fmt.Printf("obj = %#v\n", b)
}
```

But I'm guessing there is some more to this plan which isn't apparent here!

Comment: Thanks but I have already tried thsat trick. There are two problems with this.

Comment: 1. It will not work on recursive object types. That is objects inside objects and 2. The returned data is not an object of type sent in Get funtion. Thats the tricky part. I updated my question to clarify that.

Comment: What returned object? You don't return an object. b which is already the right type gets populated by the call to MustJSONDecode.

Comment: No its not, since I cannot access fields like obj.Name. Its not right format. If it were right then I could access obj.Name and every other field.

Comment: Oh i see what you are saying. I have to use the dummy object to unwrap the data. Wow so basically everything that I was doing was waste of time. So stupid I am.

Answer (score 1):

`reflect.New(objType)` returns a `reflect.Value` Which is not the thing as the interface you passed. According to the docs for [Value](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value) It is a struct with only unexported fields. the json package can't work with unexported fields. Since it's not the same object as you passed in and it's not even json encodable/decodable the json package will fail.

You will probably find the [Laws of Reflection](http://blog.golang.org/laws-of-reflection) article useful while trying to use the reflect package.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I read that thrice but one think I noticed that this article(which btw is very intimating) does not talk about creating objects from other objects. May bethe author kept that as a part of developer discretion.

Comment: You can't really use reflect to create an object of a particular type the way you describe. You can use reflect to see *if* an object is of a particular type but not to construct an arbitrary type.